# Strenghtening Achilles tendon @home.

Tags: tendons, lower-body-strength, stability

I've twisted my ankle once, it was terribly bad, I was immobilized for many month (lack of proper rehabilitation made it worse, in my country of origin you get only 'necessary' medical services from state, and rehabilitation is not considered 'necessary', no words...).

Last week, I've placed my food false when going downhill, it was a short pain, but nothing more, so I've got luck this time, however my ankle is slightly swelled so some damage was done.

It makes me worry. Apparently my stabilizing muscles are too week, I have too little coordination and I'm not enough stretched. I need some exercises to strengthen this part of my body, which appears to be my Achilles heel...

What exercises can target that tendon to make it more resistant, as well as strengthen stabilizing muscles around it? I've found out many warm-up exercises, but after long uphill, I was certainly more than warm-upped. The best exercises are those that can be done at home and don't require special (big) equipment...

Comment: You can't exercise a tendon. Tendons connect muscle to bone, the achilles anchors the calf. The ankle is tough because very few actual muscles run through there, it is all mostly tendons and ligaments.

Comment: @JohnP but you can stretch the tendon making it more flexible? It's what yogi (bears) are doing? And strengthening the surrounding muscles should also protect the tendon? It works great on knee, there should be something for heel, at least I hope it very much...

Comment: No, again you don't stretch tendons. You teach the muscle to relax instead of tense as you get to limits of flexibility. You can increase your ankle mobility, but there isn't a great way to do that other than a few swimmer stretches. I will have to think about it, I just got used to moving in that direction when I start to roll an ankle running x-country.